# Why does `tf.cond` accept python functions as arguments instead of tensors?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm wondering why the `fn1` and `fn2` arguments has to be python callables.

Also, does `tf.cond` acquire the GIL in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They provide an abstraction to define the subgraphs during the construction of the true and false branch of the conditional.

Similar to all the other operators, tf.cond only adds a bunch of nodes in the graph that is used in run calls.